# get matching items in arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I found another question on here that told how to get the matching items in 2 arrays like this:

```
matches = array1 & array2
```

However I have an array of arrays.  like:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[1,3,4,5]]
```

In this case I want to return 3 and 4 because they are in all three arrays.

How do I go about doing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
a.reduce(:&)
```

For example:

```
>> a = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[1,3,4,5]]
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5]]
>> a.reduce(:&)
=> [3, 4]
```

Comment: This is why i love ruby and rails.

Comment: @TobyJoiner Nope, that's why you love [ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)!